# Animation showing low-level plot additions

Tags: r, animation, knitr

In an animation using the `animation` package, I want to plot some points and then show *cumulatively* the successive addition of lines (or other graphic elements) to the plot.  That would be something like the use of `fig.show="all"` in a `knitr` chunk option.

Here is a simple test:

```
library(animation)
myplot <- function() {
    x <- 1:10
    y <- x^2

    plot(x, y, pch=16, cex=1.5)
    for (i in 1:(length(x)-1)) {
        lines( c(x[i], x[i+1]), c(y[i], y[i+1]))
    }
}
```

However, using `saveHTML` on this produces only a single frame.  So, I tried adding `ani.record()` to this,

```
myplot1 <- function() {
    x <- 1:10
    y <- x^2

    plot(x, y, pch=16, cex=1.5)
    for (i in 1:(length(x)-1)) {
        lines( c(x[i], x[i+1]), c(y[i], y[i+1]))
        ani.record()
    }
}
```

and run it as

```
saveHTML({
        myplot1()   
}, img.name = "myplot1", imgdir = "myplot1_dir", htmlfile = "myplot1.html", 
    title = "myplot1 test")
```

However, now what that gives is a sequence of frames showing each new line separately, rather than their cumulative effect.

Eventually this will go into a `Rmd` document run with `knitr`, but I'd like to be able to develop the animation just with the `animation` package for now, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, I'll give a partial answer to my question: What I want to do can't be done very easily with the `animation` package, because it was designed largely for animating a collection of "complete" graphic frames.

Using `ani.record()` is necessary in the loop, but my `myplot1()` attempt
didn't work because it was just recording the most recent line, not the cumulative sequence.

The version below does better, by (a) moving the `plot()` call inside the loop and (b) re-drawing all lines from `1:i` for each frame.

```
myplot2 <- function() {
    x <- 1:10
    y <- x^2

    for (i in 1:(length(x)-1)) {
        plot(x, y, pch=16, cex=1.5)
        lines( c(x[1:i], x[1:i+1]), c(y[1:i], y[1:i+1]))
        ani.record()
    }
}

saveHTML({
        myplot2()   
}, img.name = "myplot2", imgdir = "myplot2_dir", htmlfile = "myplot2.html", 
    title = "myplot2 test")
```